# SOAP client parameters wont work

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have to call a SOAP with this structure (obtained with SOAPUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
xmlns:v3='http://v3.ws.server.ldap.ws.xxx/' 
xmlns:cod='http://server/Usr/codeUsr'>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v3:getUsr>
         <cod:codeUsr>P012997</cod:codeUsr>
      </v3:getUsr>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The client is:
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ws-ldap3/wServiceV3?wsdl");

So far, I tried:

```
echo "a(TT).<br/>";var_dump($client->getUsr('P012997'));
echo "b(TT).<br/>";var_dump($client->getUsr(array('cod' => 'P012997')));
echo "c(TT).<br/>";var_dump($client->getUsr(array('codeUsr' => 'P012997')));
echo "d(TT).<br/>";var_dump ($client->__soapCall('getUsr', array('parameters' => array('cod' => 'P012997'))));
echo "e(TT).<br/>";var_dump ($client->__soapCall('getUsr', array('parameters' => array('codeUsr' => 'P012997'))));
echo "f(TT).<br/>";var_dump ($client->__soapCall('getUsr', array('cod' => 'P012997')));
echo "g(TT).<br/>";var_dump ($client->__soapCall('getUsr', array('codeUsr' => 'P012997')));
```

without success. How can I pass the parameter codeUsr?

TIA,

Comment: this should work var_dump($client->getUsr(array('codeUsr' => 'P012997'))); are you getting any error? and what's the response?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The method returned all the users -when the parameter is incorrect-, You are suggesting the (c) try. It doesnt worked.

Comment: I know it is the c try but I wanted to know the actual response with PHP and soapui, I had a similar problem and I suggest you start considering there could be something wrong with the web service because that should work fine.

Comment: btw use this $client->__getLastRequest() and $client->__getLastResponse(), add this to make them work $client = new SoapClient("path.../wServiceV3?wsdl",array("trace"=>1));

Comment: $client->__getLastRequest() string(305) " P012997 "  && $client->__getLastResponse() string(26255006) ...

Comment: I need more details in your of the response in your question so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem (not the case) using CURL. I send the XML exactly as needed.

```
$xml="<same as before>";
$sDo = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ws-ldap3/wServiceV3?wsdl"); 
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); 
curl_setopt($sDo, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml)));
$result = curl_exec($sDo);
```

Post it in case somebody else have a bottleneck and can't spend days to figure how to make it work.